# Is this a good question? - Applying actual photography information to video game screenshots

Tags: discussion

Is this a good question for this site?

**Can I use this calculation for Focal Height to get the distance to the in-game moon, using this video game screenshot, and these assumptions?**

I've seen the formula [here.](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/12437/43317)

```
distance to object (mm) = focal length (mm) * real height of the object (mm) * image height (pixels)
                          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          object height (pixels) * sensor height (mm)
```

However, I'm not sure I've figured out how to get the Focal Length, and I have no idea on how to figure out Sensor Height, so I'm going to define distance as dependent on Sensor Height... Unless someone can tell me how to calculate it from the given information...

To get Focal Length, I thought of inverting Wikipedia's Angle of View calculation equation:

"For a lens projecting a rectilinear image (focused at infinity, see derivation), the angle of view (α) can be calculated from the chosen dimension (d), and effective focal length (f) as follows:"

> [image]

Since the platform is circular, I think I can use the amount of platform that is seen, to determine Field of View, as the picture is Rectilinear, I think... But I don't know if such a process applies to in-game screenshots, given their perfect focus (sorta) on every part of a picture...

I'm also assuming that the camera is around the same height as the eyes of the girl that's not in the pit, around 5.2ft tall? And the girls in the pit are ~5ft and ~4.5ft, so I can use their leg lengths to determine the size of the pit and from there, the size of the whole platform.

Finally, I know that circular pit in the center of the platform has a tilt of around 70 degrees, due to calculating what angle a circle would have to be tilted to generate an eclipse with the given long and short diameter ratios.

But, is all of that enough to estimate a video game camera's distance to an in-game Moon? I'm assuming the moon in the picture is the size of Earth's Moon.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would have to say no. It's not a photography question, really, and while you can obviously make use of the information on the site to assist, and we'd encourage that, I think this is probably a better question for the various programming sites.